# FetchXml Query Returns Trimmed DocumentBody?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, fetchxml

We have a FetchXml query with a couple of link entities, one of which is to the `annotation` entity in order to retrieve an attached image's base64 encoded content. This is so we can display an image inline on a page using data uris.

The problem is that the image displays trimmed because the documentbody returned is actually cut off at 2,000 characters.

Comment: Just googled this problem again a year later and found my own answer. Woo!

Comment: I love it when that happens. Also hey BJ!

Comment: @MichaelBlackburn haha hey!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem ended up being an issue with the query itself. We had `distinct="true"` set on the fetch query, removing this attribute then caused the result to contain the entire documentbody of the image. Very strange.